# 403 Forbidden : You don't have permission to access

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, permissions, httpforbiddenhandler

> ### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /install/step3.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Why is it showing this error when I'm trying to install a script?

Comment: Check your permissions for the file. Make sure it can be viewed.

Comment: If you're installing something, you probably need write permissions too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question have 2 configuration problems.

- File Permission (in Filesystem)
- ErrorDocument Attribute (in Apache Webserver)

First, you can solve the permission error using 'chmod' and 'chown' command.

Try this:

1. chmod -R 777 directory (777 means allow permission for all)
2. chown -R [user]:[group] directory (generally, the same [user] and [group])

Second, ErrorDocument handle error can occur from invalid ErrorDocument attribute setting in .htacess or httpd.conf (or apache2.conf) file.

Try this:

1. Check your .htacess file in 'install/' directory. If you can not check this file, you can try 'ls -al' command in terminal. You have to find 'ErrorDocument' attribute, and remove or correct it.
2. Check your apache web server configuration file (httpd.conf or apache2.conf). If you can check 'ErrorDocument' attribute, you can try remove this attribute in file. It is temporary, so you must backup it before try suggested cases.
3. If you can not solve with 1 and 2, you can try to disable 'AllowOverride' attribute. Try to find the 'AllowOverride x' attribute and replace it with 'AllowOverride None'. Because this problem can happen from .htaccess file in parent directories. AllowOverride attribute can control allow or deny additional configuration in .htacess file.
4. You must restart the apache service after trying this. You can try 'service httpd restart' or 'service apache2 restart' command.

Good luck to your web server and you.

Comment: Setting public file permissions to `777` is **really bad**

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is check that the index.html is written in properly. Forbidden 403 usually indicates that the server is running but that the requested resource is not being found.
Then clear your cache. Additionally check your php.ini file to configure any necessary items to get your website running.

> > The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown
> >     robot) was correct, but access to the resource identified by the URL
> >     is forbidden for some reason.
>
> This indicates a fundamental access problem, which may be difficult to
>   resolve because the HTTP protocol allows the Web server to give this
>   response without providing any reason at all. So the 403 error is
>   equivalent to a blanket 'NO' by the Web server - with no further
>   discussion allowed.
>
> By far the most common reason for this error is that directory
>   browsing is forbidden for the Web site. Most Web sites want you to
>   navigate using the URLs in the Web pages for that site. They do not
>   often allow you to browse the file directory structure of the site.
>   For example try the following URL (then hit the 'Back' button in your
>   browser to return to this page):
>
> http://www.checkupdown.com/accounts/grpb/B1394343/
>
> This URL should fail with a 403 error saying "Forbidden: You don't
>   have permission to access /accounts/grpb/B1394343/ on this server".
>   This is because our CheckUpDown Web site deliberately does not want
>   you to browse directories - you have to navigate from one specific Web
>   page to another using the hyperlinks in those Web pages. This is true
>   for most Web sites on the Internet - their Web server has "Allow
>   directory browsing" set OFF.

Comment: Same Problem again :?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem. On local host it was running as I want, but when deployed (using Filezilla in my case) on the remote server, the problem occurred. with error 403 instead of 404. I think as mentioned before, It is a restricted access from the server. I only reuploaded the whole folder and every thing is perfect now.
Thanks to this community.

Answer (score -4):

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403.14 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

Comment: Don't use a script-language that creates the error (for sample 500). If you running PHP as FPM, all your ErrorDocuments are broken, if the service of FPM is broken.